# A-frame panoramic gallery with Thumb carousel

Tags: aframe

How can i add a carousel of thumbnails to my aframe panorama viewer? Do yu have a sample code. Thanks!
Thé image below shows whatsapp i want to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwYfL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

1) You need to check out on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp), or [wherever](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/) how to make a nice proper thumbnail carousel.

2) set it's z-index to 1, so it will be above the a-frame canvas.

3) make it's position fixed so it won't float away

4) make the click events on the carousel change the source of the `a-sky`, or `a-sphere`:

```
document.querySelector("#beachThumbnail").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    document.querySelector("a-sky").setAttribute("material","src","beach");
});
```

to make it more custom, you can correlate the thumbnail id's with the image name, or make a whole new attribute, and put the listener inside the a-sky:

```
document.querySelector(".carouselItem").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    this.el.setAttribute("material","src",e.srcElement.attributes[1]);
});
```

5)..
6) Profit

Live fiddle with a "thumbnail" option of switching colors [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxLquaee/).